# asp.net disable textbox to auto fill on pageload

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

In my project, when a page loads, I see that the textbox is filled with old entries. Is there a way to stop that? I want the users to fill it themselves.

I tried to use `autocomplete='off'` but it didnt work. What can I do to stop that?

Here is my html code,

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_email_change" runat="server" CssClass="blue_input lower_case" Width="240px" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: I can use jquery but there must be another solution. anyway, what do you have in mind?

Comment: no it is not duplicate. if u read carefully, autocomplete and my situation complete different. autocomplete is on key press, it suggest u old entries. but in my case, textbox is filled with old entries on pageload

Comment: I think then you should disable browser's autofill settings..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you use HTML4 or HTML5?

HTML5 Support `autocomplete="off"`